# how to replace list item in python

Tags: list, python-2.7

currently, I am trying to create the hangman game, I'm trying to write a code that tells the computer to automatically replace the "_" to the stored letter if guessed right.

here is my code below: (display is the list with dashes representing the hidden word)

note: I know this code will change the 3rd dash to the letter guessed if correct but I do not know how to write a code that will automatically detect the position in my list.

```
for letter in chosen_word:  
    if letter == guess:
    display [2] = letter
    print (display)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate over `chosen_word` and then using index to change the `display` list. For example:

```py
chosen_word = "tree"
display = list("----")

guess = "e"


for index, letter in enumerate(chosen_word):
    if letter == guess:
        display[index] = letter

print("".join(display))
```

Prints:

```
--ee
```